# drc:: drc plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, drc

I'm trying to reproduce `drc` plots with `ggplot2`. Here is my first attempt (MWE is given below). However, my ggplot2 is little bit different from base R plot. I wonder if I am missing something here?

```
library(drc)
chickweed.m1 <- drm(count~start+end, data = chickweed, fct = LL.3(), type = "event")

plot(chickweed.m1, xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "Proportion germinated", 
xlim=c(0, 340), ylim=c(0, 0.25), log="", lwd=2, cex=1.2)
```

[image]

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(chickweed)

dt1Means1 <- dt1[, .(Germinated=mean(count)/200), by=.(start)]
dt1Means2 <- dt1Means1[, .(start=start, Germinated=cumsum(Germinated))]
dt1Means  <- data.table(dt1Means2[start!=0], Pred=predict(object=chickweed.m1))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data= dt1Means, mapping=aes(x=start, y=Germinated)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(y = Pred)) +
    lims(y=c(0, 0.25)) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Edited**

I followed the methodology (with some changes) given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043751/707145).

Comment: You can always just look at `getAnywhere(plot.drc)` to see how the data is calculated in the base plot.

Comment: What would you like to change in the ggplot? It appears that the data are the same in both graphs.

Comment: @MYaseen208: So give him the bounty. There isn't any further point in keeping it open.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza: Please see the answer of dww.

Comment: Sure @42-, bounty is for dww.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NB, you can skip to the final paragraph for the simple answer.  The rest of this answer documents how I arrived at that solution

Looking at the code for drc:::plot.drc, we can see that the final line invisibly returns a data.frame `retData`

```
function (x, ..., add = FALSE, level = NULL, type = c("average", 
                                                      "all", "bars", "none", "obs", "confidence"), broken = FALSE, 
          bp, bcontrol = NULL, conName = NULL, axes = TRUE, gridsize = 100, 
          log = "x", xtsty, xttrim = TRUE, xt = NULL, xtlab = NULL, 
          xlab, xlim, yt = NULL, ytlab = NULL, ylab, ylim, cex, cex.axis = 1, 
          col = FALSE, lty, pch, legend, legendText, legendPos, cex.legend = 1, 
          normal = FALSE, normRef = 1, confidence.level = 0.95) 
{
  # ...lot of lines omitted...
  invisible(retData)
}
```

retData contains the coordinates for the fitted model line, so we can use this to ggplot the same model that plot.drc uses

```
pl <- plot(chickweed.m1, xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "Proportion germinated", 
        xlim=c(0, 340), ylim=c(0, 0.25), log="", lwd=2, cex=1.2)
names(pl) <- c("x", "y")
ggplot(data= dt1Means, mapping=aes(x=start, y=Germinated)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pl, aes(x=x, y = y)) +
  lims(y=c(0, 0.25)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Which is the same as the version you created in ggplot using predict(object=chickweed.m1).  So, the difference is not in the model lines, but in where the data points are plotted.  We can export the data point from drc:::plot.drc by changing the last line of the function from `invisible(retData)` to `list(retData, plotPoints)`.  For convenience, I copied the entire code of drc:::plot.drc into a new function. Note that if you wish to replicate this step, there are a few functions called by drcplot that are not exported in the drc namespace, so `drc:::` needs to be prepended to all calls to the functions `parFct`, `addAxes`, `brokenAxis`, and `makeLegend`.

```
drcplot <- function (x, ..., add = FALSE, level = NULL, type = c("average", 
                                                      "all", "bars", "none", "obs", "confidence"), broken = FALSE, 
          bp, bcontrol = NULL, conName = NULL, axes = TRUE, gridsize = 100, 
          log = "x", xtsty, xttrim = TRUE, xt = NULL, xtlab = NULL, 
          xlab, xlim, yt = NULL, ytlab = NULL, ylab, ylim, cex, cex.axis = 1, 
          col = FALSE, lty, pch, legend, legendText, legendPos, cex.legend = 1, 
          normal = FALSE, normRef = 1, confidence.level = 0.95) 
{
  # ...lot of lines omitted...
  list(retData, plotPoints)
}
```

and run this with your data

```
pl <- drcplot(chickweed.m1, xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "Proportion germinated", 
          xlim=c(0, 340), ylim=c(0, 0.25), log="", lwd=2, cex=1.2)

germ.points <- as.data.frame(pl[[2]])
drc.fit <- as.data.frame(pl[[1]])
names(germ.points) <- c("x", "y")
names(drc.fit) <- c("x", "y")
```

Now, plotting these with ggplot2 gets what you were looking for

```
ggplot(data= dt1Means, mapping=aes(x=start, y=Germinated)) + 
  geom_point(data=germ.points, aes(x=x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(data=drc.fit, aes(x=x, y = y)) +
  lims(y=c(0, 0.25)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Finally, comparing the data point values of this plot (`germ.points`) with those in your original ggplot (`dt1Means`), shows the reason for the discrepancy.  Your calculated points in `dt1Means` are shifted one time period earlier relative to those in plot.drc. In other words, plot.drc is assigning the events to the end time of the period in which they occur, whereas you are assigning germination events to the start of the time interval in which they occur. You can simply adjust this by, for example, using

```
dt1 <- data.table(chickweed)
dt1[, Germinated := mean(count)/200, by=start]
dt1[, cum_Germinated := cumsum(Germinated)]
dt1[, Pred := c(predict(object=chickweed.m1), NA)]  # Note that the final time period which ends at `Inf` can not be predicted by the model, therefore added `NA` in the final row

ggplot(data= dt1, mapping=aes(x=end, y=cum_Germinated)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Pred)) +
  lims(y=c(0, 0.25)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thanks @dww for very helpful answer. For your answer, what I understood that, `dt1Means2 <- dt1Means1[, .(start=start, Germinated=c(0,cumsum(Germinated)))]` is sufficient. However, it is not giving me required output. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Using only `dt1Means2 <- dt1Means1[, .(start=start, Germinated=c(0,cumsum(Germinated)))]` is not the solution. It gives the following message `In as.data.table.list(jval) :   Item 1 is of size 35 but maximum size is 36 (recycled leaving a remainder of 1 items)`.

Comment: @MYaseen208, the message is a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it.  That said, this was just the smallest change I could make to your code to get the correct plot you want - but is not the tidiest way.  Better is to construct your data correctly using the end times rather than start times (which is what I suggest in the answer already). I have edited to show how to do this.

Comment: I am struggling how to get `ggplot2` version when `curveid   = Temp`. Would highly appreciate if you have a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38289656/707145). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Getting the intuition from the answer of @dww, I had to make two little changes in my original code. Just replacing `start!=0` by `end!=Inf` in

```
dt1Means1 <- dt1[, .(Germinated=mean(count)/200), by=.(start, end)]
dt1Means  <- data.table(dt1Means2[start!=0], Pred=predict(object=chickweed.m1))
```

gives the right graph.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the solution that dww presents. Might I suggest a generalization to this solution. By adding the lines below to the self-written version of `drc:::plotdrc()` you can generalize the solution. The function takes the input of the `drc:::plotdrc()` function but outputs a ggplot-object with equal specifications as the default base-plot output of the original function.

just replace `invisible(retData, plotPoints)` with

```
result <- list(retData, plotPoints) 
points <- as.data.frame(result[[2]])
drc.fit <- as.data.frame(result[[1]]) 
names(points) <- c("x", "y")
names(drc.fit) <- c("x", "y")` 

gg_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=points, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_line(data=drc.fit, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
scale_x_continuous(trans='log10', limits = xlim) +
ylab(ylab) +
xlab(xlab) +
lims(y = ylim) +
theme_bw()
return(gg_plot)`
```