# Reproducing drc::plot.drc with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, drc

I want to reproduce the following `drc::plot.drc` graphs with `ggplot2`.

[image]

```
df1 <-
      structure(list(TempV = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L), .Label = c("22.46FH-142", "27.59FH-142", "26.41FH-142", 
    "29.71FH-142", "31.66FH-142", "34.11FH-142", "33.22FH-142", "22.46FH-942", 
    "27.59FH-942", "26.41FH-942", "29.71FH-942", "31.66FH-942", "34.11FH-942", 
    "33.22FH-942"), class = "factor"), Start = c(0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
    96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 
    144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 
    192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 
    0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 
    48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
    96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 
    144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 
    192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 
    0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 
    48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 
    96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 
    144L, 168L, 192L, 216L), End = c(24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 
    192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 
    24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 
    120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 
    192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 
    24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 
    120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 
    192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 
    24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 
    120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 
    192, 216, Inf, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, Inf), 
        Germinated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 67L, 46L, 12L, 101L, 221L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 57L, 50L, 44L, 31L, 32L, 236L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        31L, 68L, 50L, 31L, 34L, 29L, 207L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 30L, 31L, 
        55L, 27L, 22L, 4L, 273L, 0L, 0L, 46L, 64L, 16L, 8L, 15L, 
        15L, 20L, 266L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 13L, 63L, 51L, 147L, 
        172L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 26L, 92L, 31L, 91L, 14L, 7L, 185L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 59L, 36L, 50L, 273L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
        13L, 32L, 42L, 52L, 42L, 265L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 22L, 40L, 
        57L, 44L, 73L, 208L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 55L, 41L, 68L, 24L, 
        33L, 202L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 31L, 26L, 30L, 61L, 25L, 58L, 201L, 
        0L, 0L, 36L, 54L, 33L, 55L, 12L, 27L, 55L, 178L, 0L, 0L, 
        6L, 28L, 26L, 31L, 53L, 48L, 33L, 225L)), .Names = c("TempV", 
    "Start", "End", "Germinated"), row.names = c(NA, -140L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(df1)

library(drc)

dt1fm1 <- 
  drm(
        formula   = Germinated ~ Start + End
      , curveid   = TempV
  #   , pmodels   = 
  #   , weights   = 
      , data      = dt1
  #   , subset    = 
      , fct       = LL.2()
      , type      = "event"
      , bcVal     = NULL
      , bcAdd     = 0
  #   , start     =
      , na.action = na.fail
      , robust    = "mean"
      , logDose   = NULL
      , control   = drmc(
                            constr      = FALSE
                            , errorm      = TRUE
                            , maxIt       = 1500
                            , method      = "BFGS"
                            , noMessage   = FALSE
                            , relTol      = 1e-07
                            , rmNA        = FALSE
                            , useD        = FALSE
                            , trace       = FALSE
                            , otrace      = FALSE
                            , warnVal     = -1
                            , dscaleThres = 1e-15
                            , rscaleThres = 1e-15
                            )
      , lowerl    = NULL
      , upperl    = NULL
      , separate  = FALSE
      , pshifts   = NULL 
      )



## ----dt1fm1Plot1----
plot(
        x      = dt1fm1
    , xlab     = "Time (Hours)"
    , ylab     = "Proportion Germinated (\\%)"    
  # , ylab     = "Proportion Germinated (%)"    
    , add      = FALSE
    , level    = NULL
    , type     = "average" # c("average", "all", "bars", "none", "obs", "confidence")
    , broken   = FALSE
  # , bp
    , bcontrol = NULL
    , conName  = NULL
    , axes     = TRUE
    , gridsize = 100
    , log      = ""
  # , xtsty
    , xttrim   = TRUE
    , xt       = NULL
    , xtField    = NULL
    , xField     = "Time (Hours)"
    , xlim     = c(0, 200)
    , yt       = NULL
    , ytField    = NULL
    , yField     = "Proportion Germinated"
    , ylim     = c(0, 1.05)
    , lwd      = 1
    , cex      = 1.2
    , cex.axis = 1
    , col      = TRUE
  # , lty
  # , pch
    , legend     = TRUE
  # , legendText  
    , legendPos  = c(40, 1.1)
    , cex.legend = 0.6
    , normal     = FALSE
    , normRef    = 1
    , confidence.level = 0.95
    )


## ----dt1fm1Plot2----
dt1fm1Means1 <- dt1[, .(Germinated=mean(Germinated)/450), by=.(TempV, Start, End)]
dt1fm1Means2 <- dt1fm1Means1[, .(Start=Start, End=End, Cum_Germinated=cumsum(Germinated)), by=.(TempV)]
dt1fm1Means  <- data.table(dt1fm1Means2[End!=Inf], Pred=predict(object=dt1fm1))

dt1fm1Plot2 <- 
       ggplot(data= dt1fm1Means, mapping=aes(x=End, y=Cum_Germinated, group=TempV, color=TempV, shape=TempV)) + 
        geom_point() +
        geom_line(aes(y = Pred)) +
        scale_shape_manual(values=seq(0, 13)) +
        labs(x = "Time (Hours)", y = "Proportion Germinated", shape="Temp", color="Temp") +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, unique(dt1fm1Means$End))) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), labels = function(x) paste0(100*x,"\\%")) +
      # scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), labels = percent) +
        expand_limits(x = c(0, max(dt1fm1Means$End)+20), y = c(0, max(dt1fm1Means$Pred)+0.1)) +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0),
              axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25))
print(dt1fm1Plot2)
```

[image]

**Question**

There are few discrepancies in `ggplot2` output. These discrepancies occur because the `predict` function gives output in different pattern than the given levels in the data.

**Edited**

Actually `drm` function changed the order of levels of `TempV` and this is clear from `summary(dt1fm1)` output and the graph of `drc::plot.drc` output.

Comment: I've had a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780357/plotting-dose-response-curves-with-ggplot2-and-drc/37043751#37043751.    In brief, I was able to use the stat_smooth function to plot a drm model directly but for some reason this behaviour does not repeat on all machines I tested. The other option is to add predicted values to your data set and plot these.

Comment: biomiha: With the help of @dww, I figured out how to plot `drc` model with `ggplot2` for one curve (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38268934/707145)). However, I am struggling when `curveid   = TempV` is being used. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: MYaseen208: What exactly is the issue with curveid? Is it just the order of the legend items? You can change that by transforming your TempV values as factors and defining the levels (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the question, there is an issue related to `drm` shuffling the order of factor levels. Un-shuffling this mess proved more tricky than I expected.

In the end I approached this by calling the `drm` function once per factor level to build up a table of results one factor level at a time.

Doing it this long-winded way uncovered the fact that your 1st plot from `plot.drc` and the ggplot version **are both incorrect**.

Let's start by wrapping your function call to `drm()` inside another wrapper function, to facilitate calling it repeatedly for each trace:

```
drcmod <- function(dt1){
  drm(formula   = Germinated ~ Start + End
    , curveid   = TempV
    , data      = dt1
    , fct       = LL.2()
    , type      = "event"
    , bcVal     = NULL
    , bcAdd     = 0
    , na.action = na.fail
    , robust    = "mean"
    , logDose   = NULL
    , control   = drmc(
      constr      = FALSE
      , errorm      = TRUE
      , maxIt       = 1500
      , method      = "BFGS"
      , noMessage   = FALSE
      , relTol      = 1e-07
      , rmNA        = FALSE
      , useD        = FALSE
      , trace       = FALSE
      , otrace      = FALSE
      , warnVal     = -1
      , dscaleThres = 1e-15
      , rscaleThres = 1e-15
    )
    , lowerl    = NULL
    , upperl    = NULL
    , separate  = FALSE
    , pshifts   = NULL 
  )
}
```

Now we can use this wrapper to fit the drc model to each factor level in turn:

```
dt2 <- data.table()
for (i in 1:nlevels(dt1$TempV)) {
  dt <- dt1[TempV==levels(TempV)[i]]
  dt[, TempV:=as.character(TempV)]
  dt[, Germ_frac := mean(Germinated)/450, by=.(Start)]
  dt[, cum_Germinated := cumsum(Germ_frac)]
  dt[, Pred := c(predict(object=drcmod(dt)), NA)] 
  dt2 <- rbind(dt2, dt)
}
```

and plot:

```
ggplot(dt2[End != Inf], aes(x=End, y=cum_Germinated, group=TempV, color=TempV, shape=TempV)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Pred)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=seq(0, 13)) +
  labs(x = "Time (Hours)", y = "Proportion Germinated", shape="Temp", color="Temp") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

### Edit

If we run the original code in the question using a subset of the data with fewer factor levels, for example using

```
dt1 <- dt1[TempV %in% levels(TempV)[1:5],]
dt1 <- droplevels(dt1)
```

all the plots (the 2 versions in OP, and the version in this answer) give the same result.  The discrepancies only seem to arise when a large number of factor levels are used. The fact that both the ggplot and the plot.drc in OP give incorrect matching of traces to factor levels indicates that the problem is most likely to be in the `drm()` function, rather than in plot.drc.

Comment: Thanks @dww for your time and effort. What I understood from your answer that `plot.drc` bug, if that is true please report it. Thanks

Comment: @myaseen208 See my edit to this answer. After looking again, it appears that the problem seems to be in the drm function rather than in plot.drc. and it only seems to arise when a large number of factor levels are used.  My recommendation is to run the drm model one trace at a time, as i do in my answer, until this can be fixed by the package maintainers. I suggest also that you raise this with the package maintainers, and point them towards this SO page. in the mean time, i think my work-around should work for you.

Comment: Thanks @dww for your efforts. I have written an email to the maintainer of drc package and looking forward to his notice and reply. Thanks